# Integration of Power BI with SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

We have plenty of `SSRS` reports in our application. No we are thinking of moving the reports to `Power-BI` for better data visualization. Is it possible to integrate `SSRS` reports with Power-BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible from sql server 2016, on enterprise edition i think:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2015/10/28/pin-reporting-services-charts-to-power-bi-dashboards-with-sql-server-2016-ctp-3-0/